# Can I tell postgres to use a different "collation" for an integer column?

Tags: postgresql, order-by

Let's say I'm using an integer column to represent an "enum" in my application code, for a "priority" attribute.

- 0=low
- 1=medium
- 2=high

The app is operating for a while like that, and then I want to add two more

- 3=medium-low
- 4=medium-high

Now I want to be able to index this column and do queries on it using the correct semantic ordering. Is there a way to tell postgres, when creating the index and also when doing the query, that the number ordering isn't the semantic ordering?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CASE expression for the ORDER BY:

```
order by case the_column 
            when 0 then 0 
            when 3 then 1
            when 1 then 2
            when 4 then 3
            when 2 then 4
            else 5 --- everything else
         end
```

Comment: Great! And can I somehow tell the b-tree index to use this ordering as well?

Comment: I suppose the answer is, use an expression index and then do the select on that expression.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to convert the `integer`s to `real`s. Then you always can insert a new label between two old ones.

You won't waste any space, since `real` needs 4 bytes just like `integer`.

Comment: I've seen that approach before, definitely handy sometimes - but I would use 2-byte integer for the enum, so it would be a lot bigger with float.